# Checking user agent in cookies, minor changes

Tags: php, security, cookies, user-agent

When a user logins to my website I add an encrypted cookie to his browser. When he comes back, I check for various aspects including user-agent.

But it seems like very minor changes makes this check obsolete. Examples below. First one when user signin, seconds one when user come back later:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.62 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.66 Safari/537.36

Opera/9.80 (Series 60; Opera Mini/7.1.32448/30.3793; U; tr) Presto/2.8.119 Version/11.10
Opera/9.80 (Series 60; Opera Mini/7.1.32448/31.1325; U; tr) Presto/2.8.119 Version/11.10

Opera/9.80 (Android; Opera Mini/7.5.33361/31.1312; U; tr) Presto/2.8.119 Version/11.10
Opera/9.80 (Android; Opera Mini/7.5.33361/31.1325; U; tr) Presto/2.8.119 Version/11.10

Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/10B329
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/10B329 Twitter for iPhone
```

I want to continue to check for user-agent for security reasons. But I also don't want to refuse user for changes like this.

What would be the proper way in PHP server side ?

(Edit: Note that I encrypt cookie contents with salt and some random variables. So it is very hard to guess the contents of the cookie. But anybody that steals the cookie can present himself as another use. But cookie steal is another issue. But the cookie with the session id also can be stolen, which is another issue)

Comment: I wouldn't use user-agents for security, they can be VERY EASILY fooled.

Comment: It is useful to check if a user agent is the same from one request to the next, but really only within the same session, and is only part of the anti-session-hijacking story.  Browsers auto-update themselves at random intervals so in general you cannot rely on user agent strings remaining consistent between sessions.

Comment: `UA` is basically utterly useless.

Comment: No I don't check only the user agent. As I mentioned in question, I check for various aspects. I don't want to write them here. But user agent is one of the checks. I also encrypt the cookies with salts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`similart_text()` is a good solution for this.
Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

For example the similarity of these two strings is %99

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
    Chrome/29.0.1547.62 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
    Chrome/29.0.1547.66 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just gonna throw this out here. User-Agents are a bad security measure. But there's not a lot of other alternatives. So! To get the user agent string...

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

Now if your encrypting and setting it to cookies, and worried by small changes (which should only happen if the browser changes or gets updated). I would suggest stripping this info down and using basic info like OS, Hardware, and Browser Brand. There are PHP libraries available to help facilitate the parsing of these strings.

You can also salt this with the users IP address if your really worried. You can get the IP with...

$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

But remember, both of these values can be faked EASILY and are not to be trusted.